# Import Foundations/NSXMLElement.h

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch

I want to use the NSXMLElement in Cocoa/Objective-C. But when I

```
#import <Foundation/NSXMLElement.h>
```

XCode tells me: No such file or directory found. I have Foundations Framework added to the linked libraries of my project.

How can I import the NSXMLElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mac**

NSXMLElement is part of the Foundation framework, it's imported by:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

**iPhone**

NSXMLElement is not available on the iPhone.

Alternatives:
- [NSXMLParser](http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) (native)
- [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/) (framework)
- [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) (framework)

Comment: Added alternatives for the iPhone.